# Duplicate and scale edges but keep in the same mesh

Tags: edges

So I am working on a low poly car, I forgot to add more detail around the wheels, so I want to add new edges at the exact position as the current but scaled up. I am not the most advanced blender user and can't seem to find a way to basically extend these edges but keep one connected to the outer face and the other connected to the inner face of the wheel.

See:
[image]

How would I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a snappier way, but I would:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel the outer curve of the wheel-arch, Segments 2, Profile 1
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> dissolve the surplus loop on the inside of the arch
- Select the new edges, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> with <kbd>C</kbd> Loop Slide to adjust the depth of the new loop's offset..

[image]

..depending on your previous use of the Loop Slide, you may have to hit <kbd>E</kbd> to get the sliding loop to be parallel to one side or the other, and maybe <kbd>F</kbd> to flip which side.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even get the extra bevel so it was very easy. I will keep this in mind for the future. The whole side of the car is one face now so I will get that triangulated later, that is why i had problems with this.

Comment: Great! I think maybe you _should_ have got the extra bevel.. maybe that's a sign you have some double-verts in there or something, perhaps  check your topology  to make sure you'e not going to have problems with shading, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to select the huge polygon that makes up the entire fender section, and press i to inset, then move the mouse until you get the thickness you want. Granted, this will create new edges outside the entire perimeter of the selection, instead of only at the wheel hub. But in your particular case, given that you're at such a low poly stage, the extra geometry this would bring might actually be welcome.